# How to write a test in Postman to check if there is no string value in an array?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, postman

I get back a body with an array of  values.

```
[
     "test",
     "rootKeys",
     "HiveName",
     "hiveName",
     "Birthday",
     "main_hive"
]
```

I need to write a test that checks that the array has no values, like "TestCreate".
How can this be done?

Comment: Your title and question body are kind of confusing. You want to make sure some specific string is not in the array (blacklisting) or you want to make sure there is no string returned in the entire array? I assume it's the first?

Comment: I want to make sure that a certain string is missing from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `to.not.include()`.

```js
pm.test("String 'TestCreate' not in array", () => {
    const parsedResponseBody = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(parsedResponseBody).to.be.a("array");
    pm.expect(parsedResponseBody).to.not.include("TestCreate");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
pm.test("Hive Exists", function(){
         pm.expect(res.json()).to.contain.oneOf(['NewNameHive']);
     })
     pm.test('Not Exists', () => {
         pm.expect(res.json()).to.not.contain.oneOf(['newHive'])
     })
});
```

If anyone has options to improve this I would appreciate it